# How to get orders count and sum per day in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have a query like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateOnly: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": "$creation_date",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      dateOnly: "2022-01-12"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      num: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It returns something like this:

```
{
  _id: null,
  num: 184
}
```

---

Now I need to change `dateOnly` and make it work as a time range like `... WHERE DATE(created_t) BETWEEN 2022-01-12 AND 2022-02-12` in MySQL. Also, I want to get the result per day (daily). And adding something like `SUM(final_price)` to the `SELECT` statement.

So, here is the expected result:

```
[
    {
      date: 2022-01-12,
      num: 184
      sum: 25000000
    },
    {
      date: 2022-01-13,
      num: 127
      sum: 23710000
    },
    ....
]
```

Any idea how can I do that in Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering out data after converting dates to strings, is never a good idea and can lead to unexpected results. I suggest you do the following:

a. First filter out the documents, matching your date criteria, using timestamps.

b. Convert your dates to strings as desired.

c. Group the documents and calculate the respective aggregates.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      creation_date: {
        $gte: {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": "2022-01-12",
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          }
        },
        $lte: {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": "2022-02-12",
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateOnly: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": "$creation_date",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$dateOnly",
      num: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: "$final_price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As suggested in the comments, by @Wernfried, you can also try this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      creation_date: {
        $gte: {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": "2022-01-12",
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          }
        },
        $lte: {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": "2022-02-12",
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$creation_date",
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      num: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: "$final_price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: You can also use `_id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$creation_date", unit: "day" } }` - would be shorter.